# School assignments about arrays and looping through them

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

I was assigned to make the below application

> The computer inserts 20 random numbers (with values between 0 and 200)
>   in an array of 20 elements. After the array has been completely
>   filled, all elements are shown and the average of the numbers in the
>   array is determined and shown. Lastly, the difference between the
>   numbers in the array with the average is shown

I managed to make half of the program but now am at the point where I have to make the app shows the difference between each element of the array and the average and I can't manage to think of a formula to get this done !!!

this is my code so far and it Answers half of the question.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        int[] numbers = new int[20];
        Random numbergenarator = new Random();
        for(int i=0; i<numbers.Length;)
        {
            numbers[i] = numbergenarator.Next(0, 201);
            Console.WriteLine("Element "+i +" is: "+ numbers[i]);
            sum += numbers[i];
            i++;
        }
        int average = sum / 20;
        Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + average);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: homework questions don't tend to go down well, to be honest; but... what part is unclear? you have a number (the average), and you have some numbers in an array - what do *you* think it means to show the difference between those numbers in the array and the average? the first step is to know what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: You will need to add another loop.  You already have the average stored, so displaying the  difference from the average is just the current number - `average`.  For a beginner programmer, you seem to be off to a good start.

Comment: The best person to ask is probably the one who gave the assignment.  They will know what they have taught you and expect you to know/be able to work out - asking here might get you a solution, but perhaps not one that will fit in with the rest of the course, and might just muddy the waters further.

Comment: @MarcGravell Most homework questions don't go down well here, but *most* homework questions are phrased as "Here is my homework question, can someone write 100% of the code for me, even though I haven't tried anything?". This particular instance seems acceptable to me.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I disagree. "I can't manage to think of a formula to get this done !!! anyone out there HELP ! " is not a good question.

Comment: the thing is the I can't calculate the average of the " unless the loop is finished and the array is completely filled, so how can I subtract each element/number in the array from the total average of numbers

Comment: @AbdulSH You already have the average, stored in `average`.  You are allowed to have more than one loop. Just loop through all the numbers again, after you calculate the average.  That way you can compare each number to `average`.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but for readability' sake, you can take advantage of new [C# feature $tring Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings). `Console.WriteLine("Element "+i +" is: "+ numbers[i]);` vs `Console.WriteLine($"Element {i} is: {numbers[i]});"`

Comment: I've solved the issue by adding another loop !! silly me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the resolution to my issues was by adding another (for loop) for generating the difference between each element and the average of elements.
for better comprehension read the code down through :D

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    Random numbergenarator = new Random();

    for(int i = 0; i<numbers.Length;)
    {
        numbers[i] = numbergenarator.Next(0, 201);
        Console.WriteLine("Element "+i +" is: "+ numbers[i]);
        sum += numbers[i];
        i++;
    }

    int average = sum / 20;
    Console.WriteLine("The average is: " + average);

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length;)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("the difference between the average and the element " + i + 
            " is " + (average - numbers[i]));
        i++;
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, did you try to edit your question and by mistake submitted an answer to your own question?

Comment: instead of `for (int i=0; i< numbers.Length;)` followed by `{i++}` you can write this `for (int i=0; i< numbers.Length;i++)` and forget about `{i++}`

Comment: No man, I literally answered my questions, I've solved it by adding a new (for loop) !

Comment: Mark it has an answer and edit it with an explanation, don't leave it plain, have some pride in your work. It might give you points and help somebody else..

Comment: Also, you should move your increment up to the for loop: `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++;) { ... }`.